# What does an ampersand ("&") do in a put statement?

Tags: sas

I'm familiar with the `:`, and `~` modifiers in SAS `put` and `input` statements. The behaviour of `&` in an `input` statement is also fairly well documented. But what does `&` do in a `put` statement?

It seems to have a similar effect to `:`, triggering modified list output rather than formatted output, but I can't find any documentation of this behaviour.

E.g.

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  file 'c:\temp\output.csv' dlm=',';
  put Name Sex Age & 4. Height Weight;
run;
```

Comment: I don't see any evidence of documentation of this behavior.  My guess is that it either does nothing other than colon (and is just there because colon works for both input and put), or that it has some esoteric effect related to its input effect (though I couldn't see any in a brief test).  If nobody here figures it out you might try crossposting to SAS-L or communities.sas.com, there are more of the grognards there who remember how it worked in older SAS versions where it might've made a difference.  (It also might exist for compatibility with IBM Mainframes or such.)

Comment: Good suggestions. I might ask SAS themselves if they have documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the on-line documentation in the section of SAS 9.4 under INPUT Statement, List

```
&
```

indicates that a character value can have one or more single embedded blanks. This format modifier reads the value from the next non-blank column until the pointer reaches two consecutive blanks, the defined length of the variable, or the end of the input line, whichever comes first.

Restriction:
The & modifier must follow the variable name and $ sign that it affects.

Tip:
If you specify an informat after the & modifier, the terminating condition for the format modifier remains two blanks.

Here is an example from the example section:

Example Reading Character Data That Contains Embedded Blanks

The INPUT statement in this DATA step uses the & format modifier with list input to read character values that contain embedded blanks.

```
data list;
   infile file-specification;
   input name $ & score;
run;
```

It can read these input data records:

```
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+
Joseph   11 Joergensen  red
Mitchel  13 Mc Allister  blue
Su Ellen  14 Fischer-Simon  green
```

The & modifier follows the variable that it affects in the INPUT statement. Because this format modifier follows NAME, at least two blanks must separate the NAME field from the SCORE field in the input data records.

You can also specify an informat with a format modifier, as shown here:

```
input name $ & +3 lastname & $15. team $;
```

In addition, this INPUT statement reads the same data to demonstrate that you are not required to read all the values in an input record. The +3 column pointer control moves the pointer past the score value in order to read the value for LASTNAME and TEAM.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - I'm interested in the `put` statement, not the `input` statement.