# Print all columns SAS with delimiter

Tags: sas, file-writing, datastep

I am trying to print out a delimited file, without having to specify all of the columns. I can get close, but the numeric columns are always quoted:

```
DATA _NULL_;
  SET SASHELP.CARS (obs = 5 keep = Make Model EngineSize);
  FILE "foo.csv" DSD DLM=",";
  PUT (_all_) (~);
RUN;
```

**foo.csv**

```
"Acura","MDX","3.5"
"Acura","RSX Type S 2dr","2"
"Acura","TSX 4dr","2.4"
"Acura","TL 4dr","3.2"
"Acura","3.5 RL 4dr","3.5"
```

How can I achieve either:

```
"Acura","MDX",3.5
"Acura","RSX Type S 2dr",2
"Acura","TSX 4dr",2.4
"Acura","TL 4dr",3.2
"Acura","3.5 RL 4dr",3.5
```

or:

```
Acura,MDX,3.5
Acura,RSX Type S 2dr,2
Acura,TSX 4dr,2.4
Acura,TL 4dr,3.2
Acura,3.5 RL 4dr,3.5
```

Comment: See this closely related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869021/file-statement-in-data-step-to-export-comma-delimited-text-file?lq=1) .  I'm of mixed feelings on if this is a dup or not, so if others think it is i'll close it - otherwise not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~` asks for quoting.  So, you're getting quoting.

You can use `&` instead:

```
DATA _NULL_;
  SET SASHELP.CARS (obs = 5 keep = Make Model EngineSize);
  FILE "c:\temp\foo.csv" DSD DLM=",";
  PUT (_all_) (&);
RUN;
```

`&` has effectively no impact on the data (we've had a question about it once upon a time, I don't recall the ultimate answer, but basically it seems to mostly be used for this specific purpose, even though that's not its purpose).

Comment: `:` also works fine, by the way.  There are probably some other options also.

Comment: Thanks @Joe! Do you have a link for these references? I could not find it after crawling around in the knowledge base for a while

Comment: There's not really a reference for how you do exactly what you're asking.  What you're basically doing is cheating.  The purpose of the `put (a) (b)` functionality is to apply a common format/etc. to all variables in the variable list (a).  Normally you could just write your variable list out; but because `put _all_;` has a special functionality, you have to override it by forcing it into this other method.  What you put in the second pair of parens doesn't matter: just something that's not harmful, but allows SAS to think you're applying something to all of the variables in `_all_`.

Comment: You can use `(+0)` for the format list. That always seems clear to me that it will do nothing since it just moves the pointer zero spaces.